# Prevent RSpec stub from turning associated object into mock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, fabrication-gem

I've recently run into an issue that I'm surprised to have not seen before. I have classes like:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar, inverse_of: :foos
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foos, inverse_of: :bar
end
```

and I'm using [fabricators](http://www.fabricationgem.org/) like so (I know these look pointless):

```
Fabricator(:foo, class_name: Foo) do
  bar fabricator: :bar
end

Fabricator(:bar, class_name: Bar) do
end
```

and in a test (RSpec) I'm doing this stub:

```
foo = Fabricate(:foo) # I can confirm that both foo and foo.bar are correct here.
Foo.stub(:find_by_id).and_return(foo)
```

My issue is in the test, when `Foo.find_by_id` is called, it returns `foo` correctly but `foo.bar` is an RSpec mock, and saving `foo` results in this error message:

`Mock received unexpected message :marked_for_destruction? with (no args)`

How can I ensure that the association is passed through with the stub as well? I found [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rspec/SozZBmxkQMg) but can't quite decipher what it all means.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

And of course, my problem was that later on in the test I was calling `Foo.stub_chain(:bar, :property)` so `foo.bar` was naturally just an RSpec Mock.